# non-static global variable in java

Tags: java, static

Is there any way to create a variable which i can change in class A and by these changes affect what will happen in another class B. Hope you understand.

Something like this:

```
class A{
public int var = 0;

}
```

And use value of variable `var` like this:

```
class B{
if(var == 0)
   {
    System.out.println("right now, var is equal 0");
   }
else if(var == 1)
   {
    System.out.println("right now, var is equal 1");
   }
}
```

Also as you can see, var can't be static because i need to change it's value during run of app.

Comment: Not possible unless `B` has a reference to a (shared?) instance of `A`. But why wouldn't you use static for a global variable? And of course the requisite "why are you using global variables?"

Comment: There is nothing that prevents you from changing the value of a `static` variable during runtime.

Comment: Look up observer design pattern, because it looks like that's what you want -- to be notified of changes in another object.

Comment: 'Non-static global' is a contradiction in terms, and there are no global variables in Java, which makes your question doubly meaningless.

Comment: I do not get why you say "var can't be static because i need to change it's value during run of app". Static is effectively same as an instance variable. Only difference is, the "instance" here is a class object. As long as it is not final, you can change it in the runtime.

Comment: Though Observer pattern is a nice solution, but it maybe an overkill for OP given he can't even shows proper understanding on what an object instance is... Probably what he need is simply a reference to an `A` object in `B`

Comment: @AdrianShum Yes i need to reference to an A from B, how can I do it?

Comment: `class A {...} class B { A a;}` but it has nothing to do with "global".  That's why I said  you can't even show a basic understanding on what an object instance is.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it by having a reference of class B in class A so that A could also change B when it needed to. For example:

```
public class A {

    private int var;
    private B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.var = 0;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void set(final int var) {
        this.var = var;
        b.set(var);
    }

}

public class B {

    private int var = 0;

    public void set(final int var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

}
```

Comment: @SamTebbs33 Could you please guys use my `System.out.println()` so I can understand what which class does. According my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the observer-observed pattern.

```
public class A extends Observable {

    private int var = 0;

    public void setVar(int val) {
        this.var = val;
        notifyObservers();
    }

}

public class B implements Observer {

    public void init(A a) {
        a.addObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Observable obs, Object arg) {
        // Do something when A is updated
        if(var == 0) System.out.println("right now, var is equal 0");
        else if(var == 1) System.out.println("right now, var is equal 1");
    }

}
```

The  way it works is that `A` becomes `Observable`, which means that other classes can be updated when something changes in `A` (the other classes are notified by `A` calling `notifyObservers()`). The `onUpdate()` method in the observer is then called with the `Observable` (here `A`) as the first argument. If you call `notifyObservers()` with an `Object` argument, the `Object` argument in `onUpdate()` will use that value.

Here is the control flow:

A : setVar -> A : notifyObservers -> B : onUpdate

Comment: Now that's what I'm talkin' about. 1+

Comment: @SamTebbs33 Thanks for your solution. Is there any way to implement this problem? Cant extend my class of two classes.

Comment: @P.Barbra Well I have given you an example implementation here, you will need to adapt it to your own needs. Edit: I have added the code from your question to `onUpdate()` in  `B`

Answer (score 0):

Although Observer pattern suggested by other answer is actually a cleaner approach, given that OP seems don't even have proper understanding on basic concepts of Java as an OOP (e.g. what an object instance is), I believe what he is looking for is something even more basic, which is a reference to another object:

```
class A {
    private int value = 0;

    // getters and setters 
}

class B {
    private A a;

    // using constructor to have object reference populated
    // is only ONE OF THE WAYS
    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("my referred A value " + this.a.getValue();
    }
}
```

Of course you need to properly construct them.  Somewhere in your code:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B(a);
b.foo();
a.setValue(100);
b.foo();
```